# Changing text on an image

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hello I recently found in adobe there there is the capability to change text on an actual image through dynamic content - I was wondering if MC has this capability?  See my screenshot to know what I mean - I am trying to find the equivalent MC syntax [image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know about this functionality in adobe, but if it's invoking a variable, you can do the same with AMPscript using %%=v(@YourVariableName)=%%

Comment: Tried that didnt work upon furtehr investigation it seems like this syntax is EJS which I have never heard of https://ejs.co/

Comment: This looks like it is based on the image hosting service, not the mail service. So if your CMS or whatever service you are using to host your images or content accepts this kind of variable interaction, you can do this. But no, this is not something natively accepted by SFMC Content Builder. Could you fake it in Content Builder? Maybe. Would it be good and sustainable? Probably not.